# New to Rails/paperclip - Paperclip wont save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-plugins, paperclip

I'm very new to programming and I am trying to use paperclip to add a user photo to my user records. Records can be created from the add new record form without the <%= f.file_field :photo %> line and redirects properly and saves the record to the database. However, when its included on save it wants to redirect to create.html.erb instead of the users path and doesn't save the new record. It also doesn't display any errors. I have updated the users table with the photo_file_name, photo_content_type and :photo_file_size fields. Also, I'm running windows if thats any help.

Model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :venues
  has_many :reviews
  has_attached_file :photo,
    :styles => { 
      :medium => "300x300>", 
      :thumb => "100x100>" }
end
```

Controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @users = User.all
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.create(params[:user])
    if @user.save
      flash[:notice] = 'User added'
      redirect_to users_path
    else
      @user.save
    end
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

View:

```
<% form_for (@user, :html => { :multipart => true }) do |f| %>

  <p>username: <br>
  <%= f.text_field :username %></p>

  <p>password: <br>
  <%= f.text_field :password %></p>

  <p>photo: <br>
  <%= f.file_field :photo %></p>

  <%= submit_tag %>
<% end %>
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Whats shown in the development log:

> Processing UsersController#create (for
>   127.0.0.1 at 2011-01-12 22:05:56) [POST]   Parameters:
>   {"user"=>{"photo"=>#,
>   "username"=>"nghjhg",
>   "password"=>"ghjghj"}, "commit"=>"Save
>   changes",
>   "authenticity_token"=>"IlacpnqsC/iJ+41bx8tN4obOWPgirMx810l/WvohN68="}
>   [paperclip] identify -format %wx%h
>   "C:/Users/Home/AppData/Local/Temp/stream110112-5292-2yorcw-0.png[0]"
>   2>NUL [paperclip] An error was
>   received while processing:
>
> C:/Users/Home/AppData/Local/Temp/stream110112-5292-2yorcw-0.png
>   is not recognized by the 'identify'
>   command.> [paperclip] identify -format
>   %wx%h
>   "C:/Users/Home/AppData/Local/Temp/stream110112-5292-2yorcw-0.png[0]"
>   2>NUL [paperclip] An error was
>   received while processing:
>
> C:/Users/Home/AppData/Local/Temp/stream110112-5292-2yorcw-0.png
>   is not recognized by the 'identify'
>   command.> Rendering template within
>   layouts/application Rendering
>   users/create Completed in 157ms (View:
>   4, DB: 0) | 200 OK
>   [http://localhost/users]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The use of `:avatar` in the docs for paperclip is just an example. In your case it should be `:photo`. You'll need to change that in both the model and the view files.

**EDIT**

I've only just noticed this part of your controller:

```
if @user.save
  flash[:notice] = 'User added'
  redirect_to users_path
else
  @user.save # <<< here
end
```

That makes no sense. If the first save fails (returns false) you're just trying it again without changing anything? I suspect that line should be `render :action => :new`.

**EDIT 2**

Your logs show that your `identify` command can't recognise .png files. Either that or you don't have an `identify` command. Did you install ImageMagick? If so, how?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, just noticed I made a mistake in my question. I migrated the User table with avater_file_name, avater_content_type and avatar_file_size fields not photo sorry bout that. It now returns "User model missing required attr_accessor for 'photo_file_name'". I've re-migrated with 'photo' and its back to not saving.

Comment: Erm, you've changed the table column names to use `avatar_*` instead of `photo_*` but you've also updated your question to use `has_attached_file :photo` instead of `has_attached_file :avatar`. Make your mind up! Which is it?

Comment: Sorry bout that, it was a mistake in my original question i've changed everything to photo_ in the User table and my model, controller and view look like the above.

Comment: There's still a mention of avatar in your question but ok, you've removed all mentions of it in your app. So, has anything changed? Are you following along with your development log file? Paperclip should log what it's doing (or trying to do).

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, I've added whats being shown in the development log  at the bottom of my post.

Comment: I hadn't installed ImageMagick, but I have now, got the binary release and it now works! Thanks very much for the help its much appreciated!